# Recoger el valor de GET en un Select y dejar selected el valor correcto

Tags: php, sql, select

Necesito pasar el valor que recibo de un get a un Select y que el valor que recibo salga seleccionado. Hasta ahora eso ya lo he hecho, pero solo me sale la opción seleccionada por el GET, no me muestra el resto de opciones. Muestro código por si veis que estoy haciendo mal.

```
<select class="ui fluid dropdown" id="tipo" name="tipo">
   <?php
     $result_1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tipos WHERE id =" . $_GET['necesito']);

    while ($row_1 = $result_1->fetch_array()) {
        if ($row_1['tipo'] == $tipo) {
            echo "<option value='" . $row_1['id'] . "' selected>" . $row_1['tipo'] . "</option>";
        } else {
            echo "<option value='" . $row_1['id'] . "'>" . $row_1['tipo'] . "</option>";
        }
    }
  ?>
</select>
```

Comment: De que sirve el `$row_1['tipo'] == $tipo`, quieres marcar como `selected` lo que venga por `$_GET` no?

Comment: Exactamente no se muy bien de que sirve, es un código que encontre y modifique a mis necesidades, pero si no es esa linea como compruebo?? Gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: Entiendo, pero necesito que me digas que es lo que quieres que haga. Ahi no hay ningun error. Lo que yo entiendo es que quieres que seleccione en el `select` la opcion con id igual a lo que viene en el $_GET. Es eso correcto?

Comment: Estupendo!!! ahora si que funciona, voy a ver si sigo construyendo el filtrador de datos, que me esta costando la vida. Lo que al hacer respuesta no puedo poner la valida. Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas haciendo un `where id = 'loQueSea'`, esto significa que de la sentencia te va a mostrar solo los registros donde `id` sea `loQueSea`. En tu caso, lo que venga en `_GET['necesito'])`.

Entiendo que lo que necesitas es mostrar todos los registros de la tabla y que aparezca seleccionado lo que venga por `$_GET`.

```
<select class="ui fluid dropdown" id="tipo" name="tipo">
   <?php
     $result_1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tipos");

    while ($row_1 = $result_1->fetch_array()) {
        if ($row_1['id'] == $_GET['necesito']) {
            echo "<option value='" . $row_1['id'] . "' selected>" . $row_1['tipo'] . "</option>";
        } else {
            echo "<option value='" . $row_1['id'] . "'>" . $row_1['tipo'] . "</option>";
        }
    }
  ?>
</select>
```

**Los cambios son:**

- Le quitamos la clausula `WHERE`a  la sentencia ya que necesitamos todos los campos.

  ```
  $result_1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tipos");
  ```
- Luego, en el `while`, como lo recorremos todos, el que tenga id igual a  `$_GET['necesito']` lo marcamos como selected.

  ```
  if ($row_1['id'] == $_GET['necesito']) {
     echo "<option value='" . $row_1['id'] . "' selected>" . $row_1['tipo'] . "</option>";
  }
  ```